# Possible to ignore a line of code and reload page on a crash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, soundcloud

I have soundcloud URLs embeded using a gem called auto_html. Every now and then my site randomly crashes with the an error thats seems to be a timed out request from too much traffic on soundcloud? Is there a way to ignore the lines of my code that embeds the files when the request is timed out and reload the page?

Error:

```
JSON::ParserError

ActionView::Template::Error (757: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

          We were unable to process your request in time - SoundCloud
          Yikes, we were unable to process your request in time.
          Please reload the page or try again in a moment.
```

Code to be ignored in the view:

```
41:        <% if micropost.url.include? 'soundcloud' %>
42:          <%= auto_html(micropost.url) {soundcloud}  %>
43:        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a helper method that will "execute" the auto_html helper method and return its result. In this method you can surround the call with begin, rescue and on error you can return a js that will do a reload (window.location.href...).

I don't know if you can redirect through a helper method, if yes then it would be even easier.

Comment: I could just use the rails redirect_to method i suppose? I you possible give me an example of how to use the rescue on failure if you've got the time